# HTML control does not exist in current context asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm building an web application. I have a Sample.aspx file which I have asp controllers, asp grid view and etc. I want to add  to this design but when I add it I can't get it to the code behind.

eg: String val = date.value;

When I do this in the code behind it gives an error saying "date does no exist in current context".

I tried deleting designer.aspx, adding "runat = server" but still couldn't find a proper solution. Can some one please help me with this?

Edit:

This is my html controller where I add to the asp form. I need to get the date from user.

```
 <input type="date" id="date" runat="server" value=""/>
```

I use this on a jquery popup so if I use a asp:calendar, when a date is clicked jquery popup will be closed on the post back.

This is the asp back end code where I try to get the error saying....

> Error 7   The name 'date' does not exist in the current
>   context   E:\IncidentManagement\WebUI\IncidentMain\IncidentMaster.aspx.cs 77  69  WebUI

```
incidentTXNMaster.IncidentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date.value);
```

Comment: Put your example code here...

Comment: What is `date`? The error is indicating that it has no idea what the variable `date` is.

Comment: Example added guys :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be seen from the error message. `date` is being treated as a variable which has not been declared or initialised. Perhaps what you meant was

```
string val = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Comment: This should be question... Since you are not sure if that is what the OP wants

Comment: The question is implied by "perhaps what you meant was"

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. You are asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

doesn't exist in current context means that you are trying to use something that not initially declared.

so in your case, you are trying to use `date` but you have not declared it yet.

change this

```
<input type="date" id="date" runat="server" value=""/>
```

to

```
<input type="date" id="txtdate" name="date" runat="server" value=""/>
```

and then get value

```
string val = Request.Form["date"];
```

or using

```
string val = txtdate.Value;
```

Comment: It's not the solution for my problem. Thanks anyways :)